# Why is BeautifulSoup modifying my self-closing elements?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

This is the script I have:

```
import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = """
    <root>
        <obj id="3"/>
        <obj id="5"/>
        <obj id="3"/>
    </root>
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(data)
    print soup
```

When ran, this prints:

```
<root>
  <obj id="3"></obj>
  <obj id="5"></obj>
  <obj id="3"></obj>
</root>
```

I'd like it to keep the same structure. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML):

> The most common shortcoming of `BeautifulStoneSoup` is that it doesn't know about self-closing tags. HTML has a fixed set of self-closing tags, but with XML it depends on what the DTD says. You can tell `BeautifulStoneSoup` that certain tags are self-closing by passing in their names as the `selfClosingTags` argument to the constructor

Comment: AFAIK, as of `bs4` self-closing tags in `xml` mode are history.