# How to get BeautifulSoup 4 to respect a self-closing tag?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

This question is specific to [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which makes it different from the previous questions:

[Why is BeautifulSoup modifying my self-closing elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567402/why-is-beautifulsoup-modifying-my-self-closing-elements)

[selfClosingTags in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211589/selfclosingtags-in-beautifulsoup)

Since `BeautifulStoneSoup` is gone (the previous xml parser), how can I get `bs4` to respect a new self-closing tag? For example:

```
import bs4   
S = '''<foo> <bar a="3"/> </foo>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(S, selfClosingTags=['bar'])

print soup.prettify()
```

Does not self-close the `bar` tag, but gives a hint. What is this tree builder that bs4 is referring to and how to I self-close the tag?

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:112: UserWarning: BS4 does not respect the selfClosingTags argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor. The tree builder is responsible for understanding self-closing tags.
  "BS4 does not respect the selfClosingTags argument to the "
<html>
 <body>
  <foo>
   <bar a="3">
   </bar>
  </foo>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[To parse XML you pass in “xml” as the second argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#xml)

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(S, 'xml')
```

[You’ll need to have lxml installed.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml)

You don't need to pass `selfClosingTags` anymore:

```
In [1]: import bs4
In [2]: S = '''<foo> <bar a="3"/> </foo>'''
In [3]: soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(S, 'xml')
In [4]: print soup.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
 <bar a="3"/>
</foo>
```

Comment: This works by passing the list of `selfClosingTags`, but it still gives the same warning as above. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, the docs answer that question. It seems that a self-closing tag on xml mode is made automatically when the content is empty and a list should not be passed.

Comment: Right. Added a demonstration.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use BS4 to *create* a self-closing tag (using [new_tag](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag))?

Comment: @detly, if it's empty, it will be self-closing (in XML mode).

Comment: Note to self: I once passed a string named `label` to a tag such as `<b a="label"/>`, without explicit quote marks and ended up with `<b a="label/"></b>`. Moral: Make sure you add the quote marks in self-closing tags (you may be able to get away with it if the tags are paired). And another 30 minutes of my life gone...