# Python Beautiful soup insert comment in html

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to insert a comment in html using beautiful soup, I want to insert it before head closure, I am trying something like this

```
soup.head.insert(-1,"<!-- #mycomment -->")
```

It's inserting before `</head>` but the value gets entity encoded `&lt;!-- #mycomment --&gt;`. Beautiful Soup documentation [speaks about inserting](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert) a tag but how should I insert a comment as it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instantiate a `Comment` object and pass it to `insert()`.

Demo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


data = """<html>
<head>
    <test1/>
    <test2/>
</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
comment = Comment(' #mycomment ')
soup.head.insert(-1, comment)

print soup.prettify()
```

prints:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <test1>
  </test1>
  <test2>
  </test2>
  <!-- #mycomment -->
 </head>
 <body>
  test
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect thanks, one quick help is there any way to insert something before a tag start like .. { "insert here"<head>.....</head> }

Comment: @DevC try to insert it into the parent: `soup.head.parent.insert(0, comment)`.

Comment: thanks but this soup.prettify() removes closures like <meta ... />. It removes the "/>", similarly for <link ... />

Comment: Gotcha, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961497/how-to-get-beautifulsoup-4-to-respect-a-self-closing-tag.

Comment: ok this worked selfClosingTags=['link','meta'], but I have so many files to deal with.. let see.. btw thanks