# beautiful soup handle void tags and self closing tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Beautifuloup to extract html tags and delete the text. For example take this html:

```
html_page = """
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr class=tb1><td>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet</td></tr>
<tr class=tb1><td>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aliquam Tincidunt mauris eu Risus</td></tr>
<tr><td>Vestibulum Auctor Dapibus neque</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

The desired result is:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def get_tags(soup, parser):
copy_soup = soup
for element in copy_soup.find_all():
    if not element.find(recursive=False):
        element.string = ' ' # removes text from within tags
    element.attrs = {} # removes all tag parameters
#return str(copy_soup).split()
return copy_soup.prettify()

print get_tags(soup)
```

And this works great until... you have to deal with void tags and self closing tag variations between html5, html4 and xhtml. For example both `<meta>` and `<meta/>` should be outputed as `<meta>` and `<meta/>` but instead the code above results in `<meta></meta>`. I'm not sure if I need to modify my code or if the issue lies in which parser I should use.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961497/how-to-get-beautifulsoup-4-to-respect-a-self-closing-tag. Use the xml solution.